# X-13 Arima Seats with weekly data does not work

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am using R and I have weekly data (all in all 660 obeservations) and I want to use X-13 Arima-Seats from the seasonal package to seasonally adjust my data. I store my data in a ts object:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- ts(data, freq=365.25/7, start=decimal_date(ymd("2004-02-01")))
library(seasonal)
x_sa <- seas(x)
```

However, I get the error:

```
Error: X-13 run failed

Errors:
- Seasonal period too large. See Section 2.7 of the Reference Manual on program limits
- Expected argument name or "}" but found ".1785714285714"
- Time series could not be read due to previously found errors
- Expected specification name but found "}"
- Specify series before user-defined adjustments
- Need to specify a series to identify outliers
```

I also tried a shorter period of time, but the error is still the same.

Comment: Sorry, no go. X13-ARIMA-SEATS can only do quarterly or monthly.

Comment: The Reference Manual is [here](https://www.census.gov/ts/x13as/docX13AS.pdf) and it's section 2.8 (not 2.7) that has the limits: max frequency=12 (monthly) and max points = 780.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would average your weekly data by month and run the following ts object:

`ts(data, freq=12, start=c(2004,2))`

You'll lose some data granularity converting to months instead of weeks, but then the seasonal package will at least be able to process your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try STL (Seasonal and Trend decomposition using Loess). You can use it with any type of seasonality, not only monthly and quarterly.

It has automatic decomposition mstl(). So for your data the formula is:

**x_sa <- mstl(x)**

There are tuning parameters for the function **t.window** and **s.window** with help of with you are able to control how rapidly the trend-cycle and seasonal components can change. 
More details you can get from book of Rob J Hyndman and George Athanasopoulos "Forecasting: Principles and Practice". In section "Time series decomposition".